# Bad Update Data in PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

Well, I'm working around with PHP with **PDO** extension as the database driver.

I'm working on a 'changing password' scenario where things is pretty messed up for me :(

We (some *Stackoverflow* **helpers**, Kudos!) have managed to ***verify*** the password with the current password, but it doesn't update the data, as I think.

Here is the encountering **scenario**:

You are changing your password from *quora* to *stackoverflow*. We know that if you **change** the password, you cannot use the old password, but in my situation, you can use the old password but not the new one, making the new one *obselete*.

Here is an snippet of my code:

```
  $option = ['cost' => 12];
  $password = password_hash($_currentpassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $option);

  $selectpasswordsql = "SELECT `password` FROM `auth` WHERE username=?";
  $selectpasswordstmt = $conn->prepare($selectpasswordsql);
  $selectpasswordstmt->execute(array($_SESSION['account']['username']));
  $selectpasswordresults = $selectpasswordstmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $databasepass = $selectpasswordresults['password'];
  if(password_verify($_currentpassword,$databasepass)){
    if(empty($passmsgs)){
      $updatepasssql = "UPDATE `auth` SET
        `password`=?
      WHERE username=?
      ";
      $updatepassstmt = $conn->prepare($updatepasssql);
      $updatepassstmt->execute(array(password_hash($password, $_SESSION['account']['username']));
      if($updatepassstmt){
        array_push($passmsgs, 'Successfully updating your password!');
      } else {
        array_push($passmsgs, 'There was a problem executing your command!');
      }
    }
  } else {
    array_push($passmsgs, 'Your current password is wrong!');
  }
```

Comment: I fail to see a question here.

Comment: You have two `?`-placeholders, but only one value passed via `execute`

Comment: @u_mulder It'll also fail `execute(array(password_hash($password, $_SESSION['account']['username'])` can't be passed by reference, *etc*...

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly it should be: $updatepassstmt->execute(array(password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $option), $_SESSION['account']['username']));

Comment: It's my fault that I added a password_hash there, I was experimenting something and I forgot to erase that function! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please be sure that you can see errors by including following lines to top of your page.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Your following code has both logic and syntax errors.

```
$updatepassstmt->execute(array(password_hash($password, $_SESSION['account']['username']));
if($updatepassstmt){
```

- You try to re-hash $password value that is hashed of $_currentpassword. (please clearly define new password variable.)
- you haven't closed password_hash() function properly. ($_SESSION['account']['username'] passed as a second parameter.)
- you don't check execute() result which returns bool. you need to check it or you'll always get success message as $updatepassstmt will be PDOStatement object on successfull prepare() calls.

I suggest you to convert your code logic like this:

```
...
$updatepassstmt = $conn->prepare($updatepasssql);

$new_hashed_password = password_hash($_POST['new_password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $option); // replace $_POST['new_password'] with the correct one.

$result = $updatepassstmt->execute($new_hashed_password, $_SESSION['account']['username']);

if ($result){
...etc...
```

Comment: I need to sanitize the fields to avoid injections and preventing to insert some *raw* data from the fields. Thanks, I didn't knew that I was hashing the current password instead of the new password :)

Comment: @astronomicalXoom You're welcome! Actually you don't need to worry about the injections since you use prepared statement. (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)